# Mongoose running a Get on a nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So Currently the setup I have shows all the results from the users which is great but I only want to get the array called visits which the users hold.

This is how I have it set up so far:

```
getClicks() {
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; users: any }>(
        BACKEND_URL_Analytics + '/user-clicks'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          return data.users.map(user => {
            console.log(user);
            return {
              _id: user._id,
          *** visits: [user.visitCount] ****
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.userAnalytics = result;
          this.userAnalyticsUpdate.next([...this.userAnalytics]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
 }
```

These is my database structure:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueVal = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const visitsSchema = new Schema ({
  postId: {
    type: String
  },
  visitCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  }
})

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  answers: {
    type: String
  },
  visits: [visitsSchema]
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueVal);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My aim is to get the user Id which is automatically created by mongoose, as _ID which is fairly easy to do. But then I need to access the `visits: [visitsSchema]`.

This is the console.log result from `console.log(user);` :

```
{_id: "5b3f839e6633e59b673b4a4e", email: "admin@hotmail.com", password: "$2b$10$IJ71o/SSfRDoQY4r./gKaetstvka8fFhh4tk35BUD4ReXaKhw1OrC", role: "admin", visits: Array(2), …}
email:"admin@hotmail.com"
password:"$2b$10$IJ71o/SSfRDoQY4r./gKaetstvka8fFhh4tk35BUD4ReXaKhw1OrC"
role:"admin"
visits:Array(2)
0:{visitCount: 3, _id: "5b7c32015f015d5108002e88", postId: "5b5dbba4c67aad56df79f341"}
1:{visitCount: 1, _id: "5b7c32f72f457a517aaef23b", postId: "5b688fb0e90f608916e7548b"}
```

The visits array shown in the console.log contains the `visitCount` and the `postID` which I need to recover and send to the frontend. Any advice on how I can fix the map or the return values in order to get the right information. If getting the ID is too hard then I would accept just getting the `visitCount` and `postID`, So I can add that to a table and display it, thanks!

```
{
    "message": "Activities were fetched succesfully!",
    "users": [
        {
            "visits": [],
            "_id": "5b3f84246633e59b673b4a50",
            "email": "teacher@hotmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$AZad.DdvPYHS4ttkLkQMyeA5wwe49JoSuJ4DvTO8xdp13gIlmF2Xy",
            "role": "teacher",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b3f839e6633e59b673b4a4e",
            "email": "admin@hotmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$IJ71o/SSfRDoQY4r./gKaetstvka8fFhh4tk35BUD4ReXaKhw1OrC",
            "role": "admin",
            "visits": [
                {
                    "visitCount": 3,
                    "_id": "5b7c32015f015d5108002e88",
                    "postId": "5b5dbba4c67aad56df79f341"
                },
                {
                    "visitCount": 1,
                    "_id": "5b7c32f72f457a517aaef23b",
                    "postId": "5b688fb0e90f608916e7548b"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
       },
```

Ontop is my postman request from the backend maybe this helps? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your question very well. But if what you want is to get all your users's data, you need [populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). For your case, this is how you should better do:

```
const visitsSchema = new Schema ({
       postId: {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: 'Post', // Reference to your Post model
      },
      visitCount: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1
      }
})

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
         email: {
             type: String,
             required: true,
             unique: true
         },
         password: {
             type: String,
             required: true
         },
         role: {
             type: String,
             required: true
         },
         answers: {
             type: String
         },
         visits: [{
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
             ref: 'Visits', // Reference to your Visit model
         }]
});
```

Then I suppose you have your model like this:

```
userSchema.plugin(uniqueVal);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);  // <- I suppose you have this
module.exports = mongoose.model('Visits', visitsSchema); // <- I suppose you have this
```

Now you can get all informations about your user for example like below:

```
User.findOne({email: 'admin@hotmail.com'})
    .populate({
        path: 'visits',
        populate: { path: 'postId' }
    });
```

You can use populate() in multiple level.

Comment: I'm getting the user's ID at the moment which is great, I just need the values inside the array, is there no other way to do it?

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean that you just need the array "visits" with all the informations about?

Comment: So as you see in my new edit the user's ID is getting pushed from the back to the frontend fine. But I can not figure out how to get into the visits array and get those two values the `visitsCount` and `postID` @Reactør

Comment: I have posted the postman request of the backend just to maybe help understand my question? I'm not the most experienced! Sorry

Comment: What you get is normal. You have to populate your visits data before returning them back as I post in my answer.

Comment: There is only few changes to do. You don't even need 15 minutes. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179635/discussion-between-andrew-and-reactor).